# Labels in TikZ are all in the lower left corner of the tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I have a problem concerning labels in Ti*k*Z. My labels are all positioned in the lower left corner of the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{birkjour}
%\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
%\usepackage{a4kopka}
%\pagestyle{empty} \topmargin-18mm \textheight265mm \textwidth166mm
%\parindent0pt
%\oddsidemargin-5mm
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=18mm}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
%\newcommand{\H}{\mathbb{H}}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\T}{\mathbb{T}}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\rb}[1]{\raisebox{1.5ex}[-1.5ex]{#1}}
\newcommand{\dis}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\cal}{\mathcal}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corrollary}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{convention}[thm]{Convention}
%\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[thm]{Example}

\newtheorem*{ex}{Example}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


%wie vom Journal der Geometrie gefordert:
\setlength{\parskip}{1.3ex plus0.3ex minus0.3ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
%ENDE wie vom Journal der Geometrie gefordert

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%\input pagenumbers

    \begin{document}
%hier Figure1
\centering
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \coordinate (a_0) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (b_0) at (6,0);
  \coordinate (u) at (4,0);
  \coordinate (z) at (6,2);
  \coordinate [label=above:$s(u)$] (u')  at (5,1);
  \coordinate (c_0) at (6,1.25);

  \draw (a_0) -- (b_0);
  \draw (a_0) -- (c_0);
  \draw (b_0) -- (z);
  \draw (u) -- (z);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Can somebody tell me what the problem with the label s(u) is?

Thanks.

[image: positioning of "s(u)" is wrong]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please try to make your code compilable with a standard class like `article`. If possible. Right now, I am not able to easily reproduce the image you are showing.

Comment: Just to supplement that: when I just take the picture and put it in a standard class, the label appears where expected.

Comment: @NadjaFärber Even with your [birkjour.cls](https://github.com/spencerparkin/MathPapers/blob/master/VersorsThatGiveNonUniformScale/birkjour.cls), I couldn't reproduce your problem. Please provide a working example showing that error.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just tried it myself with the standard class article and it worked like expected. I think there must be a conflict with the birkjour class or some previous settings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a problem with the PDF viewer.